# How to remove items adjacent to border of image

Tags: c++, opencv, border

I have a binary image containing white nuclei on a black background.
For my processing I need to eliminate from the image those nuclei that have been partially clipped by the border.

Below is an image, for this case I would like to remove the four nuclei at the top border, and the four at the bottom. How can I do this with OpenCV?

[image]

I need to eliminate those nuclei touching the border.

Comment: ***... and it's urgent! Please!*** Seriously? This doesn't matter at all, if it's urgent for you. IMHO it isn't urgent for the majority of researchers here :P ...

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this question, but I am not sure why people are voting to close because it is too broad.

Comment: I'm sorry. But thank you, anyway. =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scan the borders of the image and when you find a white pixel [flood fill](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill) with black.

You will want something like:

```
uchar white(255);

// do top and bottom row
for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y += image.rows-1)
{
    uchar* row = image.ptr<uchar>(y)
    for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; ++x)
    {
        if(row[x] == white)
        {   
            cv::floodFill(image, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Scalar(0), (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(200));
        }
    }
}
// fix left and right sides
for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; ++y)
{
    row = image.ptr<uchar>(y)
    for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x += image.cols - 1)
    {
        if(row[x] == white)
        {   
            cv::floodFill(image, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Scalar(0), (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(200));
        }
    }
 }
```